# missing credentials in aws config for dynamo upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a quick node app that would upload a json file to dynamo db but I keep getting a `missing credentials in config` error.

Here is my upload js

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var fs = require('fs');

AWS.config.update({
    region: "us-east-1",
    endpoint: "dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
    accesskey: "Axxxxxx",
    secretkey: "QQhxxxxxxxxx"
});

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

console.log("Importing ach into DynamoDB. Please wait.");

var allACH = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('ach.json', 'utf8'));

allACH.forEach(function(movie) {
    var params = {
        TableName: "ACH",
        Item: {
            "lastname":  movie.lastname,
            "firstname": movie.firstname,
            "employeeid": movie.employeeid,
            "hrs":  movie.hrs
        }
    };

    docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
       if (err) {
           console.error("Unable to add item", movie.employeeid, ". Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
       } else {
           console.log("PutItem succeeded:", movie.employeeid);
       }
    });
});
```

and then the error I get back is this:

```
Importing ach into DynamoDB. Please wait.
Unable to add item 78 . Error JSON: {
  "message": "Missing credentials in config",
  "code": "CredentialsError",
  "time": "2016-10-20T18:14:26.314Z",
  "retryable": true,
  "originalError": {
    "message": "Could not load credentials from any providers",
    "code": "CredentialsError",
    "time": "2016-10-20T18:14:26.314Z",
    "retryable": true,
    "originalError": {
      "message": "Connection timed out after 1000ms",
      "code": "TimeoutError",
      "time": "2016-10-20T18:14:26.313Z",
      "retryable": true
    }
  }
}
```

I think my credentials are in the upload.js file but why are they not being picked up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Config.html#update-property).

`accesskey` should be `accessKeyId`

`secretkey` should be `secretAccessKey`

Also, you don't need to set the endpoint if you are using the default endpoint. Setting the region is all you need to do.